# Transcode job failed in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

Unable to trigger transcode jobs

Issue Summary: IAS had some failed transcode jobs for project PROJECT_NUMBER. These were retriggered and roughly ~950/1115 passed but 122 failed.

Project Number: PROJECT_NUMBER

Job ID:
projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/us-west1/jobs/JOB_ID,

Location: us-west1

Job Config See job config:
Source File(s):

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and analyzed these 3 files, they are all corrupt and have syntax and bitstream errors, they were not captured by the customer properly prior to upload,
please request that they capture them properly and make sure that they can play them back with VLC without issues prior to upload processing

```
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=64\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=64\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=76\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=70\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=70\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=64\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=84\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=64\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=84\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=99\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=64\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=81\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=65\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): AC EOB marker is absent pos=68\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
{"type":"log","msg":"av_log(level=ERROR): Concealing bitstream errors\n","line":"init.cc:37","level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2021-07-22T20:52:33.879Z"}
```